# SQLite conditional insert or replace

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to insert or update a record into a sqlite database, and only update the value if the new value is greater than the old.

The schema is:

```
 CREATE table IF NOT EXISTS SearchTable
   (Owner INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Generations INTEGER DEFAULT 0)
```

I've tried commands like this:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO SearchTable(Owner, Generations)
 VALUES (?, MAX((SELECT Generations FROM SearchTable WHERE Owner = ?), ?))
```

but it gives me a null value for the Generations.

I could use some help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO SearchTable(Owner, Generations)
SELECT ?, MAX(Generations) FROM SearchTable WHERE Owner = ?
```

Comment: Thanks peterm.  I ended up using:
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO SearchTable(Owner, Generations) 
SELECT ?, MIN(?, COALESCE(Generations, 999)) FROM SearchTable WHERE Owner = ?