# Insert and Update Query In Android SQlite

Tags: android, sqlite, if-statement, insert, sql-update

I am Inserting and Updating the table By using below code

```
int rowsaffected = db.update(MyDatabaseHelperDon.TABLE_CURRENT, values,MyDatabaseHelperDon.VARIABLE_CURRENT + " = " + "\"" + var + "\"",null);

if(rowsaffected == 0) {
        db.insert(MyDatabaseHelperDon.TABLE_CURRENT, null,values);
}
```

where  MyDatabaseHelperDon.TABLE_CURRENT is my table name, 'values' is my Content Values, MyDatabaseHelperDon.VARIABLE_CURRENT is column name, 'var' is the Variable present in the Column.

This Code is working Fine. Now For this i need to add If Condition like 'if(value != 400)'  if it satisfies then only it should update or insert.

Please Guide me How to achieve this.

Comment: You can check before calling the insert/update function. Please post the code of calling insert function.

Comment: db.update will return integer value, if value is updated it will return 1 else 0, if it is zero i am Inserting the Value. Insert Function is written, Please check the code

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can try something like this:

```
private void insertUpdate ()
{
  // Your Insert / Update code here...
     int rowsaffected = db.update(MyDatabaseHelperDon.TABLE_CURRENT, values,MyDatabaseHelperDon.VARIABLE_CURRENT + " = " + "\"" + var + "\"",null);

     if(rowsaffected == 0) 
     {
        db.insert(MyDatabaseHelperDon.TABLE_CURRENT, null,values);
     }
}

public void callingMethod()
{
    int value = 0;// Initialize here 
    value =    // process this value further based on your logic....
    if (value !=400)
    {
        insertUpdate ();
    }
    else
   {
        // when value is 400
   }

}
```

Comment: value here is the column name, if 400 is not present in column value in table then i need to update

Comment: @user3705553: you can use a where condition for Update. Or,You can have a select query before calling the insert update method .

Comment: May be this link can help you for update with condition : http://stackoverflow.com/q/9453651/3492139

Comment: if i use where condition for checking value condition it will return 0  if value is equal to 400, and insert query will insert 400 again :(

Comment: So thinking of writing Insert and Update on Same Query. Can u Please Help How to write this

Comment: For insert and update in same query refer : <http://stackoverflow.com/a/3635038/3492139> and <http://stackoverflow.com/q/15540019/3492139>.

Comment: @ Nishanthi Grashia Thank u for your Valuable Time :) Will try and Implement as in above Links

Comment: @user3705553: Please check the grey tick mark next to this answer to accept as answer if it helps! Also, when you have enough reputation, try upvoting answers that helped you!